# Correct user input not matching array values

Tags: java, arrays, input, matching

I've written a portion of code to take a user input, match it to a string value and then use a related double value to make calculations:

```
double [] currency = new double[] {0.05,0.10,0.20,0.50,1.00,2.00,5.00,10.00,20.00,50.00,100.00};
String [] currencytext = {"$0.05","$0.10","$0.20","$0.50","$1.00","$2.00","$5.00","$10.00","$20.00","$50.00","$100.00"};
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < currencytext.length; i++) {
    boolean valid = false;
    while(!valid){
        System.out.format("$%.2f remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: ",sum);
        String payment = keyboard.next();
        if(payment.equals(currencytext[i])){
            sum = sum - currency[i];
            if(sum == 0) {
                System.out.print("You gave " + payment);
                System.out.print("Perfect! No change given.");
                System.out.print("");
                System.out.print("Thank you" + name + ".");
                System.out.print("See you next time.");
                }
                }
        if(!(payment.equals(currencytext[i]))) {
            System.out.print("Invalid coin or note. Try again. \n");
                }
        if(payment.equals(currencytext[i]) && currency[i] > sum){
            System.out.print("You gave " + payment);
            System.out.print("Your change:");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when it gets to user input, it doesn't match any string values except for $0.05. It seems to me like its not iterating through the array properly but I can't figure out why. Is anyone able to see a problem here?

Comment: I've fixed the code as per suggestions. I just don't understand how to get the loop to check every value in the array for each individual user input instead of getting stuck on the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution for your problem

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    double [] currency = new double[] {0.05,0.10,0.20,0.50,1.00,2.00,5.00,10.00,20.00,50.00,100.00};
    String [] currencytext = {"$0.05","$0.10","$0.20","$0.50","$1.00","$2.00","$5.00","$10.00","$20.00","$50.00","$100.00"};

    String payment = keyboard.next();

    double sum = 100; // <- Working example - Read sum from keyboard entry

    while (sum > 0) {

        boolean paymentFound = false;

        for (int i = 0; i < currencytext.length; i++) {

            if (payment.equals(currencytext[i])) {

                sum = sum - currency[i];
                paymentFound = true;

                if (sum == 0) {
                    System.out.println("You gave " + payment);
                    System.out.println("Perfect! No change given.");

                    // System.out.print("Thank you" + name + ".");

                    System.out.println("See you next time.");
                    break;
                } else if (sum < 0) {
                    System.out.println("You gave " + payment);
                    System.out.println("Your change:" + (-1 * sum));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!paymentFound) {
           System.out.println("Invalid coin or note. Try again. \n");

        }

        if (sum > 0) {
            System.out.format("$%.2f remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: ", sum);
            payment = keyboard.next();
        }
    }
```

while-loop will continue until the payment is fullfilled.

for-loop traverse the arrays until a suitable payment is found

- If suitable payment is found we substract it from `sum`. We use `break` to exit the for-loop in both cases. There is no need to keep searching.
- If no suitable payment is found [`!paymentFound`], we keep on asking.

  ```
      if (!paymentFound) {
         System.out.println("Invalid coin or note. Try again. \n");

      }

      if (sum > 0) {
          System.out.format("$%.2f remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: ", sum);
          payment = keyboard.next();
      }
  ```

The program will end when (sum < 0), in which case the while-loop exits.
I have use `println` instead of `print` to improve message legibility.

Answer (score 0):

## Too many flaws to point out.

#### However,

When the `currencytext[i]` does not match `payment`, it executes this code:

```
System.out.print("Invalid coin or note. Try again. \n");
System.out.format("$%.2f remains to be paid. Enter coin or note: ",sum);
payment = keyboard.next();
```

So, it executes this for **all** the times that your input does not match `currencytext[i]`.
And, in this block, you have

```
payment = keyboard.next();
```

So, it asks for new input, in this block itself. Hence, you get the said output for all inputs except `$0.05`.

As far as `$0.05` is concerned, your first `if` block executes successfully, and prints no output. So, it moves to the next iteration of the while loop, where again, `payment` remains the same (`$0.05`), but `currencytext[i]` becomes `$0.10`. SO they do not match, and you get the said output.

**How to correct this:**

With this code, you need to do a **lot** of corrections.

I suggest you again start from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't fit, it sets valid to true, so the code just has the chance to check against the first item at `currencytext[0]`, which is `$0.05`. Then `!payment.equals(currencytext[i])` is also true, and your code prints the lines there. Your `else if`s are also not properly nested.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know how you are reading input. One improvement you can do is write reading input code in for loop.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for (... ) {
....
String payment = scanner.nextLine();
....
}
```